# Knockout.js no data displayed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am just getting started with knockout.js and am having some trouble. I fairly new to web development in general also. I have looked through all the tutorials but cant seem to get anything to work in a MVC4 application that I am playing with.

Here is the simplest version which I am trying to get to work. It is the same as the intro tutorial on the [knockoutjs site](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro)

Here is my controller:

```
namespace KnockoutMvcTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my View:

```
@model dynamic

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->

<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bert";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
</script>
```

All that gets displayed in the browser is First Name: Last Name:

Sorry for such a basic question but I have been stuck at this point for over a day now. All the examples I look at include entity framework connection and models. For now I just want to understand how knockoutjs works for bindings and I'll get to all that later.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you included knockout js reference properly.

Comment: most probably not, where does this need to be referenced? As I say I am very new to web development.

Comment: either in layout.cshtml or in the same view wherever you want.but it should be before your ko code.

Comment: well that is exactly the problem. just added the line `<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>` to the top of the _Layout.cshtml file. Apologise for the stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST say that the 'firstName' and 'lastName' are observables.

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
}
```

Comment: This is also mentioned in the Step 2 of the tutorial that you have mentioned in your post.